# Mathematica, check if a variable is in a range

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, range, inequality

I am writing a program with a variable called cond which might equal something like Or[x < -2, 0 <= x <= 4].

Is there a good way if checking if another variable like x which might equal something like 4 satisfies the condition? Like if x==3, then SomeFunctionX=[cond,4] would return True?

Comment: old question i know, but mathematica's interval operations can be useful. see `IntervalMemberQ`

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, you are looking for `Between` as in `Between[x,{min,max}] = min<=x<=max` yielding `true` or `false` upon the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is. Try:

```
checkCond[x_, left_, right_, right2_] := Or[x < right2, left <= x <= right]
checkCond[3, 0, 4, -2]
checkCond[5, 0, 4, -2]
checkCond[-3, 0, 4, -2]

(*=> True 
     False
     True 
*)
```